# ASP.NET MVC and User Authentication with NHibernate

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, authentication

I am about to start a new application and am excited about using asp.net mvc and nhibernate. However, the big "problem" is how I handle the user authentication stuff. What are some ways those used to using nhibernate and MVC solve this problem?

My thought is let asp.net do its own thing and I do my own thing database wise. Am curios if I should role my own using the provider model and nhibernate, if I can figure out how. Or is there a way to integrate current code that is in the mvc example into nhibernate?

Comment: which example is THE mvc example?

Comment: The one that comes with the default mvc app.

Comment: You mean with the visual studio template, with the homecontroller, etc?

Comment: yes. I called it an example since I wasn't sure what else to call it. Sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can still use the ASP .NET 2.0 Membership APIs from ASP .NET MVC.

Comment: I am curios if I should rewrite them using nhibernate for data access or leave them be.

Comment: It's not necessary. You already have a object-oriented API. The data access has been taken care of for you. You could wrap the APIs to add functionality or make them easier to use if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000204/best-practice-to-join-nhibernate-and-asp-net-membership-role-profile-services) and Manuel Abadia has written a custom NHMembershipProvider [here](http://www.manuelabadia.com/blog/PermaLink,guid,3b6ccb3f-2f2a-4dcb-a414-605371a00618.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for linking to this. I am needing to migrate this app to somewhere else and this will make life a bit easier. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

4 guys from rolla have an excellent post if you want to buil your own provider on top of the asp.net membership API : https://web.archive.org/web/20211020114106/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/110310-1.aspx